# Why do icons in fonts have a lot of whitespace above them?

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, svg

I am trying to include a custom font for its icons from: http://aristath.github.com/elusive-iconfont/

However, there is a large amount of space above the actual icon when I try to view it. I opened the font in MS Word (from insert symbol and then choose the installed font) and it has the same problem which leads me to believe that the problem is with the font. The font was generated from an svg. I tried to upload the svg to http://icomoon.io and redownload it and the new font has the same problem.

Here is the code that I am using to render the font:

```
QLabel *test = new QLabel;
test->setText(QString::fromUtf8("\ue002\n\ue003"));
test->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);
test->setStyleSheet("color:red;font-family:'Elusive-Icons';font-size:20px;margin:0px;background-color:black;line-height:0.1");
test->setMargin(0);
test->setWordWrap(true);
test->setFixedWidth(75);
test->show();
```

How do I make it so that there is no space above the icon?

Comment: Well, when the font has these metrics, Qt will per default use a label size of that font. You have to tell Qt not to do so. Did you try negative margins / paddings in the CSS? (I think margins won't work, paddings could work.)

Comment: @leemes negative padding has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with the elusive-icon font (http://aristath.github.com/elusive-iconfont/). I have verified that FontAwesome does not have this problem (in ms word or my program).

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of the elusive-icons font.

I've noticed that this issue exists when viewing the font in IE and android 2.3 browsers. However I currently don't know why this is happening and would love to hear any suggestions people might have on how to fix this...

Comment: An interesting note to add is that it isnt just ie and android; its MS Word too! (and also my app which uses QT). Is it possible that the font is that way but somehow the browsers that it works in are collapsing the margins or something similar?

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but just an update on this: The font was updated a few months ago and this issue no longer exists. It was a bug with the icomoon.io app that was used to create the font.